# How can I execute python script which converts xml-json and vice versa in Java

Tags: java, python, json, xml, jython

I have written a java code which can execute the python script. Also, I have the Python script that converts xml-json and vice versa. how to pass the python xml method and python xml path in java code .Can someone help me with the java code to resolve this issue.

Below is the Py script and the java code which I am trying to execute to call the python script and its methods. Please help me with the java code.

Python script:

```
import json 
from json import loads
import xmltodict 
from dicttoxml import dicttoxml

def ConvertXMLtoJSON(xmltxt):
    my_dict=xmltodict.parse(xmltxt)
    json_data=json.dumps(my_dict)
    print(json_data)
    return json_data

def ConvertJSONtoXML(jsontxt):
    json_obj = jsontxt
    xml = dicttoxml(loads(json_obj), attr_type=False)
    print(xml)
    return xml
```

Java code:

```
import org.python.core.PyObject;
import org.python.util.PythonInterpreter;

interface PyFunction{
    
    String XMLPath= ".xml file path";
public void ConvertXMLtoJSON(String XMLPath);
}
    
public class Conversion {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PythonInterpreter interpreter = new PythonInterpreter();
        try {
            interpreter.exec("from PythonScript import ConvertXMLtoJSON");
            PyObject ConvertXMLtoJSON = interpreter.get("ConvertXMLtoJSON");
            PyFunction function = (PyFunction) ConvertXMLtoJSON.__tojava__(PyFunction.class);
            function.ConvertXMLtoJSON("python script path");
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            e.getMessage();
            e.toString();
        }
```

Comment: What exactly do you need help with? What is the problem?

Comment: Why are you calling Python from Java when you could easily do this in Java natively?

Comment: Underscore-java can convert xml to json and vice versa.